# what must be the block size of data in couchbase to go to rereduce?

Tags: view, couchbase

While running map reduce in couchbase, how large should be data to run rereduce part. Does rereduce depend on size of data or is there some other thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when I start using Couchbase, I have same problems. Rereduce data must be **less then 64KB**
This is from [docs](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/):

> The reduce() function is designed to reduce and summarize the data
>   emitted during the map() phase of the process. It should only be used
>   to summarize the data, and not to transform the output information or
>   concatenate the information into a single structure.
>
> When using a composite structure, the size limit on the composite
>   structure within the reduce() function is 64KB.